# Installed nginx and passenger but can't find passenger.conf

Tags: nginx, passenger

I've installed nginx + passenger by these commands

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger
```

and it shows 'passenger is already the newest version

'[image]

I want to `include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;` in my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

But I can't find passenger.conf in /etc/nginx/

[image]

so when I do `sudo service nginx reload` and `sudo service nginx restart`

It fails like this

[image]

Isn't it automatically installed after passenger+nginx installing succeed?

Any idea to solve this issue?

Thanks